# asp.net MVC 4 simple sorting

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using ASP.net MVC4 and am trying to accomplish a simple sort , so far I have found how to make the whole database sortable - by using ActionLink buttons in my View (failed to make it work btw...), but what I am trying to accomplish is a permanently sorted database.

My view and controller are both scaffolded at the moment, no changes made to this part. I am trying to make the record with the least TimeRemaining to always show up on top of the list.

Thanks!

My Database:

```
public class EquipmentDataBase    {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Name")]
    public string equipment { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Inv.Nr.")]
    public string InventoryNumber { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Location")]
    public string Location { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage ="Please specify date")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayName("Next Inspection")]
    public DateTime NextInspectionDate { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage ="PleaseSpecifyRegistrationDate")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime RegistrationDate { get; set; }
    public string Responsible { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan TimeRemaining 
    {
        get
        {
            return (NextInspectionDate - DateTime.Today); 
        }
    }
```

My Controller:

```
namespace PeriodicInspections.Controllers {
public class EquipmentDBController : Controller
{
    private EquipmentDbContext db = new EquipmentDbContext();

    // GET: EquipmentDB
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.equipment.ToList());
    }
```

Comment: How is your Controller Looks like? Sorting usually done there. Please post controller code

Comment: I have added the code from my controller's `index` `ActionResult`  because I want the sort to be performed upon Index action trigger

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have it sorted by the same criteria, the best approach is to sort them at database level. You can achieve this by changing the code in the controller as follows:

```
// GET: EquipmentDB
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(db.equipment.OrderBy(x => x.NextInspectionDate).ToList());
}
```

The `OrderBy` sorts the data by `NextInspectionDate`. This property is present at database level in contrast to the helper property `TimeRemaining` that is only available in the .NET code. As regards the sort order, this will make no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Use Linq. instead of

```
return View(db.equipment.ToList());
```

use

```
return View(db.equipment.ToList().OrderBy(e=>e.TimeRemaining );
```